# Google Cloud Print sometimes gives false errors

Tags: java, google-cloud-print

I have a Java application that uses the Google Cloud Print API (https://github.com/jittagornp/GoogleCloudPrint) to print pdf's. In most cases it works like a charm but every now and then (approx 1 out of 100) it gives an error back which looks like this "Det går inte att göra ändringar i ett avslutat jobb". 
Roughly translated to english it reads: "Can't make changes to a finished job"
The kicker is that the pages prints perfectly every time, with or without the error.

Code looks like this for every call to GCP:

```
    public static SubmitJobResponse submitPrintJob(String filename, String type){

        String jsonTicket;
        String printerId;

        SubmitJobResponse response = null;

        String jobtitle;

        jobtitle = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // Login to GCP
        GoogleCloudPrint cloudPrint = gcpLogin();

        jsonTicket = "{'version':'1.0','print':{'vendor_ticket_item':[],'color':{'type':1},'copies':{'copies':4}}}";
        printerId = session("printerlabel"); 

        try {

            // Get file as byte array
            Path path = Paths.get(filename);
            byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Ticket ticket = gson.fromJson(jsonTicket, Ticket.class);

            String json = gson.toJson(ticket);

            //create job
            SubmitJob submitJob = new SubmitJob();
            submitJob.setContent(content);
            submitJob.setContentType("application/pdf");
            submitJob.setPrinterId(printerId);
            submitJob.setTicket(ticket);
            submitJob.setTitle(jobtitle);

            //send job
            response = cloudPrint.submitJob(submitJob);
            Logger.debug("PrinterID => {}", printerId);
            Logger.debug("submit job response => {}", response.isSuccess() + "," + response.getMessage()); 
            if(response.isSuccess()) {
                Logger.debug("submit job id => {}", response.getJob().getId());
            }

            cloudPrint.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.warn(null, ex);
        }

        return response;

    }
```

The API uses a call to "/submit?output=json&printerid=" at GCP so why does it say that I'm trying to change a finished job - I'm not submitting a job id - only printer id.

How do I get rid of these false errors?

Comment: Had an idea that the job title had to be unique but in my tests with a static job title I could not reproduce the error